# Predefined symbol to tell armeabi-v7a apart?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there a pre`#define`d symbol in Android NDK/GCC that would let me distinguish between armeabi and armeabi-v7a builds?

For now, I make do with following lines in Android.mk

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CPPFLAGS) -D ARMv7
endif
```

but that's kinda crude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For runtime support have a look into [$NDK/docs/CPU-FEATURES.html](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/CPU-FEATURES.html).

or see [machine/cpu-features.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/arch-arm/include/machine/cpu-features.h) for various possible defines.